# Why array response not getting in JSON with PHP MySQL API

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

I am developing an API with `PHP` and `MySQL` database in which, it receives the `POST` parameters and sends back the response as `JSON`. I am using the query and relevant parameters which should return an array of 3 rows, but it is not returning a single row. Here are the records that should be returned

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+------+----------+
| rollno |        sub        |    date    | year | presenty |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------+----------+
|     12 | Maths             | 02-10-2019 |    2 | p        |
|     12 | Physics           | 02-10-2019 |    2 | p        |
|     12 | Computer Networks | 02-10-2019 |    2 | a        |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------+----------+
```

The code to retrieve this is as follows:

```php
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['rollno']) && isset($_POST['date'])){
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $rollno = $_POST['rollno'];
    $date_tmp = date_create($_POST['date']);
    $date = date_format($date_tmp,'d-m-Y');
    $att = array();
    $fetchatt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE year=".$year." AND rollno=".$rollno." AND date=".$date);
    while($row = $fetchatt->fetch_assoc()){
        $att[] = array('sub'=>$row['sub'],
                      'presenty'=>$row['presenty']);
        $response['att'] = $att;
    }
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['message'] = "Retrieval Successful";
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I am sending `POST` parameters(using ARC REST client chrome extension) as follows:

```
rollno: 12
year: 2
date: 02-10-2019
```

In response, I am getting only this

```
{"error":false,"message":"Retrieval Successful"}
```

instead, the response should also contain an array of the matching records above

Comment: you are overriding the value of $att in response array

Comment: @AhmedAli I am using the same technique in another file, and that is working

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: date format looks culture-dependent. Did you try to use the following format for dates: YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: @EvgenyGorb as the date is saved in the DD-MM-YYYY format in database, I am converting the date first to match that type and then it is used in query

Comment: it seems that your sql query isn't working. Your while loop and json_encode is working properly

Comment: @AhmedAli I tried it in SQL editor of `phpmyadmin`, by entering these parameters directly. It worked perfectly there

Comment: You're missing the quotes around the date value in your query,. That would also be solved by using prepared statements instead

Comment: @sman You should not store dates as strings in the database. there can be date convert issue where the date you entered is interpreted as '10-02-2019'

Comment: add empty string after `$date`

Comment: @AhmedAli - What would that solve?

Comment: try this - `$fetchatt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE year=".$year." AND rollno=".$rollno." AND date='".$date."');`. `$date` should be in single quote.

Comment: @EvgenyGorb to avoid the conversion issue, I have put the date_format() function, which will convert it in appropriate format

Comment: @BhaskarJain Thanks, your suggestion solved my question.

Comment: You're just making everything harder for yourself by storing dates in a custom format and as varchars in the database. Dates should be stored as `date` in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` since MySQL then can use that value directly for sorting and such. Now you would need to convert the dates into a format that MySQL can use, to be able to do sorting etc. That't can became a real performance bottle neck.

Comment: @sman posted this as answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this - 
`$fetchatt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE year=".$year." AND rollno=".$rollno." AND date='".$date."');`.

`$date` should be in single quote.

Comment: **Warning!** With this code, you will be wide open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: sman, Please keep in mind @Magnus suggestion and modify your query accordingly.

Comment: I would recommend that you edit your answer to be secure as well. Show the _real_ solution. Now it's saying _"try this"_ and then in the comments you're basically saying, _"but you shouldn't do it like this"_.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to verify how your SQL queries look like, especially if the are depending on user's input. Try to log queries into a file and then open that file and check queries using MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin, or even output them to the page (in testing environments only). This prevents you from obvious syntax errors in your code.

Also I suggest you to enable errors logging for your website

Comment: Please explain further how all this helps to solve the problem

Comment: As I understood, the problem was in syntax error in the query and that code could throw an error. By logging such errors you can understand what goes wrong, and by looking on actual query you can detect syntax errors

Comment: So, logging queries alone does not solve the problem? Then why not add something to the answer that does? ;)

Comment: If the author of the question added a logging of queries or errors, he would saw a problem with that query very fast

Comment: If you know that already, why not help to solve this problem?

Comment: His particular problem was solved in another answer. My answer points to how to get rid of such problems at all, since the author can have similar problems in other places of his code.